# Does the nearest function on a G1000 allow for listing of anything other than nearest airports?

Tags: navigation, avionics, g1000

In non G1000 GPS systems, I have seen several pages for selecting the nearest airport, VOR, NDB, intersections, and waypoint, but in a G1000, I can only seem to get a listing of the nearest airport, but have to manually enter VORs.

Am I missing something, or does the G1000 not have nearest functionality for these other categories of identifiers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The G1000 and G500 do indeed have pages for the nearest VOR, NDB, Intersections, and user defined waypoints. [The  G1000 Integrated Flight Deck Pilot’s Guide](https://static.garmincdn.com/pumac/190-00498-07_0A_Web.pdf) gives a list and flowchart / interface map for these.

[image]

Comment: Turns out it only works on the FMS knob for the MFD, isn't that right?

Comment: If you mean that the large view “Nearest” page only works on the MFD, you are right. This large view has several “Nearest” options. The small, bump out window on the PFD should show a list of the nearest airports. But, NDBs, VORs, etc, don’t seem to be available on the PFD.

Comment: "NDBs, VORs, etc, don’t seem to be available on the PFD" - This is what threw me off and caused me to ask this.